# Unable to locate element - Java/Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to select the highlighted element below (which is a "window close" button):

[image]
There is one other element with class='icon-Dismiss' on the page, but none with class='dialog-close'.

What I have tried so far:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='icon-Dismiss' and @class='dialog-close']"))
```

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dialog-close"))
```

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentBox']"))
```

In all cases however, I receive the following error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can select this element?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.contentBox div.icon-Dismiss.dialog-close"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='contentBox']//div[@class='icon-Dismiss dialog-close']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-Dismiss.dialog-close"))
```

Also, make sure this element is not in an iFrame.  If it is then you will need to switch to the iFrame first before you can find the element.

Answer (score 0):

try this `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` if that dialog box is an alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to locate then
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.icon-Dismiss.dialog-close"));

but if you want to just close the alert then alert().dismiss(); will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the window pop up 
try : driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

if this is application these locators should work

Note : make sure you are using waiting till popup appearing on page